# Div popup of a movie or image

Tags: javascript, html, modal-dialog, floating

I am looking for a Javascript that will pop up a modal floating div which can hold an image and will ghost our the full background of a web page.

Sort of like the way the movie pops up here in this [Apple trailer](http://www.apple.com/trailers/independent/capitalismalovestory/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Lightbox 2.0](http://www.huddletogether.com/projects/lightbox2/)

> Overview
>
> Lightbox is a simple, unobtrusive script used to overlay images on the current page. It's a snap to setup and works on all modern browsers.

[How to use Lightbox](http://www.huddletogether.com/projects/lightbox2/#how)

Comment: I used Lightbox for a website of mine - very easy to implement.